# The possibility of an image classifier using quantum computer architecture?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, machine-learning, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

Consider an exhaustive database of all contour images that can ever be created on a 16x16 grid. Out of the $2^{256}$ unique possibilities, could a quantum computer classify all the resulting images using metrics like Hamming distance when compared to another ready-made but smaller contour dataset?
Hypothetically could we create an image classifying model using quantum computing architecture?
[image]

If yes then what would be the time complexity of such an algorithm?

Comment: Also wouldn't this mean that at the specific resolution of 16x16, all the contour images that can ever be made would have been classified, making it easier for image generators to work off of an exhaustive contour database? All they would need to do is color the objects?

Comment: Would this even be viable. Would it be faster or slower than conventionally processing all the images using normal computers?