# The possibility of a Quantum image classifier

Tags: quantum-algorithms, resource-request, research

I want to create an exhaustive database of all possible contour images(B&W) with their image tags, for a given resolution.

By classifying every single image possible for the resolution, I want to reduce the task of image generators(If a genration query is:"5 and 0", the model just needs to search for "5"+"0" and color the image).

[image]

Realistically how long would it take to generate all possible random noise for a given resolution?

Also how long would it take a 256 qubit quantum computer to perform classification(100 classes) on all these generated images?

Assume that the input image's resolution is 16x16, with only black and white pixels.

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/33777/55

Comment: what does "generate all possible random noise" mean here? Generate how, on a classical computer, as in, having a database of all possible images of the given resolution? This doesn't seem to have much to do with quantum computation. "*how long would it take a 256 qubit quantum computer to perform classification*" with what algorithm, and encoding the images in the quantum computer how? There's no definite answers for these things. Many proposals for image classification with quantum computers, but very few (if any) general results about time scalings and such

Comment: Thank you. The related question was my own. I am trying to implement this idea however I have doubts regarding its viability. Generating images using brute force, either black or white pixels(Contour images only). Conventional and quantum architectures would both take a lot of time, but is there an estimate for the time they might take?
There might not be a proper estimation for the image classification time but how many iterations would it take to achieve using the best QML classification on a quantum computer with 256 qubits?